# How to remove text from WooCommerce customer_order_completed email via php?

Tags: woocommerce

I can't seem to figure out (without using a template) how to remove this text from the customer_completed_order email. :

```
 'We have finished processing your order.'
```

I am hooking just below it with some new text to replace it:

```
 add_action( 'woocommerce_email_before_order_table', 'fs_action_woocommerce_email_responder',20, 4);
```

Comment: If you go to templates/emails/customer-completed-order.php you will see that this text doesnt have any filter or hook.

Comment: I see... so it must be a template override.